# Character C-function, misconception on its behaviour

Tags: c, function, stdio

An exercise asked to write a function that:

- reads a sequence of alphabetic characters (without memorizing the sequence) that ends only when the users enters '\n'.
- returns 1 if the number of capitalized letters went beyond the lower ones of at most an integer m, entered by the user, or 0 else.

I tried with the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int read(int p,char c)
{
    int M=0,m=0,d;
    char A,Z,a,z;

    while(c != '\n')
    {
        if(A<=c<=Z)
        {
            M++;
        }
        else if(a<=c<=z)
        {
            m++;
        }
        scanf("%c",&c);
    }

    if(M-m>0)
        d=(m-M);
    else 
        d=0;

    if(d==0)
        return 0;
    else if (d<=p)
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a,h;
    char k;

    scanf("%d", &h);
    scanf("%c", &k);
    a=read(h,k);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

At this point, trying to execute the program with the gcc command, i noticed that the program was taking just the integer, let's say 2, and gave back 0 as if it entered in the function without taking the second scan on the character.

Besides the formal misconception and errors about the program and c function that i'm glad you rectify,

I was trying to understand, because as they say i'm trying to be self-taught, how `scanf` function and function work in general, when and to who priority is given.

For example in function `read` it's not clear to me when the value i'm returning to the function are taken putting a higher if as i did.

Comment: `stdin` still has the `'\n'` character; second `scanf` takes `'\n'` for `k`.

Comment: `A<=c<=Z` is two conditions, not 1. you need to separate them.

Comment: `A`, `Z`, `a`, and `z` are all uninitialized variables.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I'm sorry i think i understood what you're saying but i don't know how to fix it,you're saying that giving let's say int k=9 and pressing enter the char h is taking the 'enter' button i'm pressing ?

Comment: @nullp0tr@p._phidot_ I'm sorry i think i could use char variables and then assign to them their integer value from ascii,is that correct ?

Comment: @p._phidot_I'm sorry i think i got this one,could i say if (A<=c && c<=Z) ?

Comment: Yes you need to assign the letters to those variables, or you can just use single quotes around the letters to immediately compare them, without using any extra variables.

Comment: @jacopoburelli Yes, I believe that is happening.  Maybe you need a loop to consume remainder of input.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Do you have an idea on how to do that ? the function keeps doing that, if i enter 2 returns me 0 right afterwards.

Comment: @jacopoburelli I'm not sure what the best way is but maybe something like: `while(getc() != '\n') continue;`

Comment: @FiddlingBits I tried c=getchar() and the while but doesn't work, i'm gonna figure out something i hope, thanks!

Comment: `if(A<=c<=Z)` should be changed to `if('A'<=c && c<='Z')`, same with the check for between 'a' and 'z'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to do what you probably expect

```
if(A<=c<=Z)
```

... for all sorts of reasons. Firstly, the values of `A` and `Z` are uninitialized. Second, the logic is written to be read by a mathematician, not a C compiler.

You almost certainly wanted this:

```
if('A'<=c && c<='Z')
```

... and remove the four variables `char A,Z,a,z;`

Note that use of character constants such as `'A'` and `'Z'` assumes a runtime environment using ASCII character sets. If you're interested in a more portable solution, you can look up `isupper()` and `islower()`

Comment: I see,thank you, but why can't i initialize A,z,a,z; as char variable and then, omitting the ' ', consider them as integers?

Comment: You can initialize four variables if you want, but you don't win anything. At the end of the day they are constants.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot,i understood everything you said, the problem of the programm now is that i enter the integer let's say 9 the programm ends because i entered the '\n' for the scanf that is taken as the second character

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long time since I did any low level input code, so I can't help with that